# What means function f on set X?

Tags: functions

This is more a language question as I'm not a native English speaker and it is very hard to find answers in the internet.

Given a function $f: \mathbb{R} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ and let $B \subset \mathbb{R}$.

In a paper the author states "$f$ on $B$ ". Does it mean we look at $f$ just with the domain $B$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example: "$f$ is continuous on $B$" means: in each $x_0 \in B$ the function $f$ is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the statement: $f$ on $B$ is the same as taking the restriction of $f$ to $B$, $f\mid_{B}$. You are then considering a function $$f\mid_{B}: B \rightarrow f(B).$$